# Cartoon Series with a man in black clothing making a metal/rock monster appear after throwing rock cubes

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

One of the first cartoons I watched.

A man in black clothing (like red outlining) throws three rock cubes, with red writings on them, and a gigantic metal/rock monster appears.

Maybe he gets his arm taken off and replaced with a blue metallic one.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) as well as by making a greater effort with spelling and grammar

Comment: Hi there. That's a bit terse at the moment, but no worries - we have a [handy guide for story-id](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028) :) Could you please take a look, see if that triggers any more memories you could [edit] in?

Answer (score 4):

I think you may be talking about [Di-Gata Defender](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Di-Gata_Defenders). You can read more about it - including a brief plot summary - in the linked Wikipedia article.

Back to your question, the few details you provide seem to match said show:

- characters fight using cube-shaped rock-like rune dices, covered with weird symbol. While not every spell cast using the runes is a summon spell, it is indeed possible to use the dices to summon "guardian entities". The rock monster you remember may have been Kragus, the guardian commonly used by the main character of the show.

  [image: Seth and his guardian Kragus]
- speaking of the main character, Seth - he indeed wear black clothes. The clothes are decorated with some red writing, again matching you description.
- later in the show, Seth loses his right hand and has it [replaced by an artificial one](http://digatadefenders.wikia.com/wiki/Seth%27s_Mech-Arm). This is actually a major plot device in the story.

  [image: Seth's Mech Arm]